# How to send executable react-native app to another people to work/test with

Tags: react-native, testing, environment, scrum

Hay dear People!

We are developing a React-Native-App for Android and IOS and have several branches of the App. Our new Scrum-Master has no much knowledge about things like npm, code, git etc.
So i have the question, how can i make a builded App for testing for people who does not have a dev-enviroment? Like "Hey, i have a new feature, could you pls test it?" --> Making a build, send this build to this person without the dev-enviroment, he can use it and test it.
Some hints would be great!

Answer (score 1):

For IOS you can put the app in TestFlight, and for Android, you publish the app for internal testing in Playstore and download apk bundle.

Android:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1XDMau5-YE&ab_channel=ScottEasley

IOS:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuL7lGEYQV8&ab_channel=derren